# How to change database in laravel5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5.1

I am just starting to learn laravel. I had given a database name (eg: mydatabase1) while beginning. Now want to change the db(eg: mydatabase2). I have updated the new database name `database.php and .env files`. Still when I run a query in the model

`$users = DB::table('tbl_users')->limit(1)->get();`

It gives me error like this:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mydatabase1.tbl_users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from 'tbl_users'
>   limit 1)

means its still considering first configuration. I wonder where i have to update to reflect the db name update. Please help

Comment: You may need to clear your config cache. Try running `php artisan config:clear` and see if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the web server to apply new changes in .env file. Even after that if you are still getting same error check your newly added configs in dababase.php as well as check  whether you have created database with the given name ('mydatabase1')